# How is the definition of differentiability of a function of two variables logically equivalent to that function's having tangent planes?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $X \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ be an open interval with $a \in X$. Let $f:X \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function. Suppose that $f'(a)$ exists. That is,
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = f'(a). \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
With a bit of algebra we have,
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a) - f'(a)(x-a)}{x - a} = 0.
$$
If we consider the function $h: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ defined by $h(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$, the graph of which is the tangent line at $(a, f(a))$, then the above implication simplifies to,
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - h(x)}{x - a} = 0. \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
Geometrically, it means that the distance between $(x, f(x))$ and $(x, h(x))$ gets to $0$ faster than the distance between $(x, 0)$ and $(a, 0)$ gets to $0$ as $x$ approaches $a$. And we can, by working backwards, show that $\eqref{eq2} \implies \eqref{eq1}$, proving that they are logically equivalent. Thus, $f: X \to \mathbf{R}$ is **differentiable** at $x \in X$ if $\eqref{eq2}$ holds.

Let's now consider functions of two variables. When we try to define differentiability of functions of two variables, we observe that the mere existence of the *partial derivatives* isn't enough, nor is it enough that the function has *directional derivative* in each direction. How do we know all these if we haven't yet defined differentiability for functions of two variables? We want differentiable functions to have tangent planes because then the "nice" properties of differentiable functions of one variable would hold for their analog in two variables, such as "smoothness". Thus, the geometric definition of differentiability of functions of two variables must be that the function has a tangent plane at the point where it is differentiable. Now, the only thing left is to find the analytic definition.

Let $D \subseteq \mathbf{R^2}$ be an open region with $(a, b) \in D$. Let $F: D \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function. Then $F$ is **differentiable** at $(a,b)$ if $F_x(a, b)$ and $F_y(a, b)$ exist, and the function $H: \mathbf{R^2} \to \mathbf{R}$ defined by,
$$
H(x, y) = F(a, b) + F_x(a, b)(x-a) + F_y(a, b)(y-b),
$$
satisfies,
$$
\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} \frac{F(x, y) - H(x, y)}{\lVert (x, y) - (a, b) \rVert} = 0.
$$

The argument goes like this: Just as in the single variable case, the distance between the tangent plane $z = H(x, y)$ and the surface $z = F(x, y)$ must get to $0$ faster than the distance between $(x, y)$ and $(a, b)$ get to $0$ as $(x, y) \to (a, b)$.

But how can we be sure that the single variable case applies to higher dimensions? Since otherwise, the geometric definition of differentiability might not be consistent with the analytic one. It makes sense that $F(x, y) - H(x, y) \to 0$ must be true, but how do we know that $\lVert (x, y) - (a, b) \rVert ^2 \to 0$ shouldn't be the case, or any other arbitrary choice?

Comment: Best linear approximation should mean that the error is $o(\|\vec x - \vec a\|)$.